# Non-zero exit status trying to install packages

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and when I tried to install the "tidyverse" package I get a non-zero exit status message on some packages. I'm programming on macOS Catalina version 10.15.5. Any solution around this problem?
I ran this

> install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE, repo = 'https://mac.R-project.org')

And then got several errors with this text

> - installing *source* package ‘glue’ ...
>   ** package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** libs
>   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glue’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/glue’
- restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/glue’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Please give us more than this, as it could be *anything*. Starters would be copy the text from your console (including the code you typed in to initiate the process) as well as the errors. Then [edit] your question here, start a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and paste that in there. Only then will we be able to really say much about this.

Comment: When you ran `install.packages()`, did it ask you if you want to install from source? It would probably be better to say "no" to that question. Seems like you might not have a development environment set up to compile packages correctly.

Comment: No it did not ask me that, I was able to download some packages manually but not "broom", "dbplyr" or "modelr". I get this error message
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘Rcpp’ 1.0.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘broom’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/broom’

Comment: Solved it, I had to delete an re-install the "Rcpp" package to a newer version